# 3.6.4 Tiff files won't open in premiere. Same project with 3.5 works just fine

Tags: output

I encountered a problem in 3.6.4. When the output is set to tiff, premiere won't open the files but same project file rendered with same settings in 3.5 works just fine. Also After Effects seem to open both files without a problem.

Same thing seems to happen to all renders in 3.6.4 making it unusable for my purposes.

Also the file size seems to be different.

Anyone have an idea what's happening here?

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Unless there is evidence to the contrary, I'd say this is a bug, that affects Blender's, handling of TIFF files. It may very well be an intentional change, that turned out not to work as expected. BSE is not involved in the development of Blender, and therefore cannot help resolve bug. They should be reported to https://projects.blender.org/.

Comment: Thank you. I reported this now.